# Zend_Form: when print elements of form in view- form tag dod't created

Tags: zend-framework, webforms, zend-form, zend-form-element

Problem:
When  print elements of form in view, form tag don't created

**My View:**

```
<?php
/****** print elements and inser label:: have to be done in this way for integrate cushycms ********/
echo $this->form->empty;
?>
 <label>Ad Title</label>
 <?php
 echo $this->form->adtitle;
 ?>
<label></label>
 <?php echo $this->form->adbody; ?>
```

**MY Form (part of the code):**

```
class MyForm extends Zend_Form
{
function init(){
   $empty = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden("empty");
        $empty->removeDecorator('Label');
        $title = new Zend_Form_Element('adtitle');
        $title->removeDecorator('Label');

        $title//->setLabel('Ad Title')
                    ->setRequired('true')
                    ->addFilter('StripTags')
                    ->addFilter('StringTrim')
                    ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
                    ->setAttrib('MAXLENGTH',100)
                    ->setAttrib('Size',106);

        $title->getValidator('NotEmpty')
                    ->setMessage('Company Name can not be empty');

        $body = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('adbody');
        $body->removeDecorator('Label');
}
}
```

**The html that I get (form tag not exist):**

```
<dd id="empty-element">
<input type="hidden" name="empty" value="" id="empty"></dd> <label>Ad Title</label>
 <dd id="adtitle-element">
<input type="text" name="adtitle" id="adtitle" value="" MAXLENGTH="100" Size="106"></dd><label></label>

 <dd id="adbody-element">
<textarea name="adbody" id="adbody" onKeyDown="javascript:limitText(this.form.countdown,400)" onKeyUp="javascript:limitText(this.form.countdown,400)" rows="24" cols="80"></textarea></dd> <label>chras left (maximum 400): </label>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add the form tag by your self.

```
    <form action="<?= $this->escape($this->form->getAction() ?>"
          method="<?= $this->escape($this->form->getMethod() ?>"
    >
```

Or use

```
echo $this->form;
```

Comment: <form action="<?= $this->escape($this->form->getAction() ?>"
          method="<?= $this->escape($this->form->getMethod() ?>"
    >

not working, its only display without values of action and method <form action="" method="">